# 2 questions- aside with inline block & responsive content

Tags: css, responsive-design

I hope that someone here can help me resolve an `<aside>` element. I've been researching multiple sites with no success.  I have tried a number of different scenarios to pull the aside up alongside the page div, but for some reason it won't move.

There are two codepen elements which you can look at to see the full code
http://codepen.io/Cornucopia/pen/PNwxLZ?editors=1100
http://codepen.io/Cornucopia/pen/YqXpEr?editors=1100

A second question I have is why the first pen shows both the longer title name (one with 'and' and the shorter with '&') while the second one is successful at switching the title text for the larger layout. (I want one shorter title for ipad & one longer title for monitor)

I thank you in advance very much for your time and look forward to hearing your thoughts.
good day

Comment: here is the first codepen - http://codepen.io/Cornucopia/pen/PNwxLZ?editors=1100
here is the second codepen - http://codepen.io/Cornucopia/pen/YqXpEr?editors=1100

Comment: Can you show where you want the asides to end up? They look OK to me. The answer to the second question is, because the first pen doesn't have the `header .lg {
    display: none !important; 
    }` the second one has in its media query.